# Typescript: accessing nested object values of interface keys with special characters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an AuthProfile object that returns a dynamic range of keys:

```
interface appMetadataProps  {
  signupContext: string
}

interface AuthProfileProps {
 [key: string]: string | boolean | appMetadataProps 

}
const authProfile: AuthProfileProps = Auth.getProfile();
```

I know that the authProfile will contain one key that is a string url. I also know that that the url key will have an object as its value which will contain the key 'signupContext'

```
let context =
      authProfile['http://myapp.com/app_metadata'].signupContext
```

^^ However I am getting an error when trying to access the .signupContext value. My initial thought was that since the the dynamic keys in the AuthProfileProps interface can have a type of appMetaDataProps then typescript should not give me any issues accessing the value of the signupContext key.

What I am I doing wrong here?

I get the following error message:

```
Property 'signupContext' does not exist on type 'string | boolean | appMetadataProps'.
  Property 'signupContext' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)
```

--- Other Option ----

My other option is to explicitly to define 'http://myapp.com/app_metadata' as a key in the AuthProfileProps Interface. But typescript doesn't recognize it as a key because of the colon (:) in the key name. How do I specify key names with special characters?

```
interface AuthProfileProps {
 [key: string]: string | boolean ,
 http://myapp.com/app_metadata : appMetaDataProps

}
```

Comment: What’s the error message exactly?

Comment: @deceze updated post with error message

Comment: So, nothing to do with special characters. It’s just that the property could be one of three different types, two of which don’t have a property `signupContext`. You need to tell Typescript that you’re very sure which of the three types your value is for it to ignore that potential error.

Comment: @deceze I see now. I have updated the post to include another option but this time I am getting stuck on the special characters in the key name. Any insight?

Comment: put quotes around a key with special characters like `interface Foo { unspecial: string; "!!special!!": string }`.

Comment: @jcalz thanks that worked! honestly can't believe the answer was so obvious (face palm emoji)